# Magento: app/code/local vs. app/etc/modules

Tags: magento-1.7, directory-structure

A lot of literature on the web teaches the difference between app/design and skin
and goes to great length to describe all of their subdirectories and how they relate
to each other. However I am struggling with another part of the Magento directory tree.
What is the difference in the purpose of the app/code/local and app/etc/modules .
While custom code goes in app/code/local is app/etc/modules where the code needs
to be declared to actually appear in the admin panel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle your assumptions are correct.

The `.xml` files in `app/etc/modules` are used to generally manage all the modules (assigning code pools, declaring dependencies, switching them on and off).

The declarations in these `.xml` files of `app/etc/modules` is what makes modules "appear" in the admin panel under `System > Configuration > Advanced` (but they do *not* make module menus, tabs, grids or the like appear in the admin panel. That's the job of your modules configuration files).

The `app/code/local` folder contains local modules and their files themselves, like the controllers, observers, blocks, helpers and configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

app/code/local is local code pool for magento modules. If you have a purpose to change the logic somehow, local code pool is the place where everything should be done.
app/etc/modules is a place where you can put main config file for your module, which can help the system to understand about your module.

To get better idea, visit: http://knowledge.santanu.net/developer-guide-for-magento-module-structure-and-codepool/